# How do I use an image content control without getting a corrupt document?

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2010, templates

I'm trying to create a Word dotx template wherein I put a logo in a content control. When I change the wrapping from in line to square and save and close the template, I get a corrupt document error when trying to reopen the template. Is there anyway this can work, considering the following constraints?

- The template is either left to right with the image on the right side or right to left with the image on the left side.
- The user should not easily (accidentally) be able to move the image (this is why I wanted to use the content control with prevent content control deletion and content editing)
- When the user inserts text next to the image, it should not move the image nor end up in front of behind the image.
- Track and accept/reject changes should be possible.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Word.  What version are you using.

Comment: Word 2010, but some other users in our office have 2007. I've yet to test it on that version.

Comment: **I will wait for you to do that.**

Comment: Okay this is odd. In 2007 the wrapping options are greyed out. It's also totally unclear to me if it's possible to somehow position the content control and if so, how you do that in 2007.

Comment: @Emst - I don't know to be honest.  I say its a bug because if you do something in word, the resulting action, shouldn't corrupt the Word document ( unless your using one version to create the document and another to read the created document ) then that would be a case of feature parity.